# Grouping folder contents universally in XP

Tags: windows-xp

I want to arrange all my folder contents in Windows XP so all of them are grouped by type.

Can this be done for all folders and sub folders just by configuring it in the main(parent) folder rather than individually.  Is there a universal setting (configuration option)?

I checked folder options, and it can universally hide/show its folders/sub-folders and some other settings, but not this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You open Computer, and set the settings you want. Then go to Tools>Folder Options>View, and click "Apply to All Folders".

From there on out, when you open a new folder, they will be in that order (you may need to close the first window once). You can then also change any individual folder that you don't want with those settings, in other words, exceptions.

[image]

Comment: I know this can be done, but what I need is grouping all folder and sub-folder contents by type.

Comment: Either I do not understand you, or you don't realize that the "Apply to All Folders" will do just that. It is not just for the settings listed there, like for hidden files, etc. Sort by Type, and then hit the Apply button.

Comment: ok I got it Thanks. :) When I sorted it and did `apply to all` , it worked.